# IOS - Need to display Latex format text?

Tags: ios, latex

I have the following text containing latex commands.

Simplify.

```
3 \(\dfrac{1}{2} + \biggr[4 + \biggl\{\dfrac{1}{2} \div \biggl(3\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} \biggl) \biggl\} \biggr] \times 1\dfrac{1}{2} \)
```

I have already tried using iosMath but it does not wrap the whole text in my view. I'm told iosMath does not support new line character(\n), is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\\` as the newline character in your syntax.

Also,

1. `bigr` and `bigl` are [not supported](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath#future-enhancements) in iosMath.
2. When specifying the string in Objective-C, you will need to use two back slash, instead of one. `\\` instead of `\`.
3. `\dfrac` will be just `\frac`.
4. Take a look at the examples given [here](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md).
5. You can use [this tool](http://www.hostmath.com) to try out syntax quickly in browser.

Finally, here is what worked for me:

`3  (\frac{1}{2} \\ + [4 + [{\frac{1}{2} \div (3\frac{1}{2} \ - \frac{1}{2} ) ]}] \\  \times 1\frac{1}{2} )`

Comment: You can get `\dfrac` with `\displaystyle\frac` (as per https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/issues/59)

Comment: Try using `\left` and `\right` instead of the unsupported `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Comment: i got your above mentioned changes. But the issue with adding a line break still persists. '\\' is only adding some space but not giving any line break.

Comment: Did you add a third backslash - remember each backslash needs an additional one when specified inside an Objective-C string. Also add a space after it as well: `\\\   `